# Create svg animation from 4 parts of svg

Tags: svg

I have to create blinking eye effect from svg files. I have small experience in creating such things. How can I do that? From starting to the first svg code to the last (black circle) and reverse.

I have 4 files:

```html
    
    <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 
    0 64.5 65.01">
      <defs>
       <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <rect class="cls-1" x="0" y=".25" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <g id="Group_242" data-name="Group 242">
    <path id="Path_1026" data-name="Path 1026" d="m32.25,14.36c13.2-.06,25.45,6.83,32.25,18.15C64.64,14.69,50.32.14,32.5,0,14.69-.14.14,14.19,0,32c0,.17,0,.34,0,.51C6.8,21.19,19.05,14.29,32.25,14.36"/>
    <path id="Path_1027" data-name="Path 1027" d="m32.25,50.65C19.05,50.72,6.8,43.82,0,32.5c-.14,17.81,14.18,32.36,32,32.5,17.81.14,32.36-14.18,32.5-32,0-.17,0-.34,0-.51-6.8,11.31-19.05,18.21-32.25,18.15"/>
    <path id="Path_1028" data-name="Path 1028" d="m18.25,32.5c0-7.73,6.27-14,14-14s14,6.27,14,14-6.27,14-14,14h0c-7.73,0-14-6.27-14-14"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" data-name="Path 1029" class="cls-2" d="m23.77,31.66c5.8-1.48,7-2.68,8.48-8.48,1.48,5.8,2.68,7,8.48,8.48-5.8,1.48-7,2.68-8.48,8.48-1.48-5.8-2.68-7-8.48-8.48"/>
    </g>
    </svg>




    <svg version="1.1" id="Warstwa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 64.5 65" style="enable-background:new 0 0 64.5 65;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <rect y="0.2" class="st0" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <g id="Group_242">
    <path id="Path_1028" d="M18.2,32.5c0-7.7,6.3-14,14-14s14,6.3,14,14s-6.3,14-14,14l0,0C24.5,46.5,18.2,40.2,18.2,32.5"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" class="st1" d="M23.8,31.7c5.8-1.5,7-2.7,8.5-8.5c1.5,5.8,2.7,7,8.5,8.5c-5.8,1.5-7,2.7-8.5,8.5
        C30.8,34.3,29.6,33.1,23.8,31.7"/>
    <g>
    <path d="M32.2,50.7C19,50.7,6.8,43.8,0,32.5C-0.1,50.3,14.2,64.9,32,65s32.4-14.2,32.5-32c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5
            C57.7,43.8,45.5,50.7,32.2,50.7z"/>
    <path d="M32.3,0C14.3,0-0.3,14.6-0.3,32.5H0C6.4,26.8,18.5,23,32.2,23s25.8,3.8,32.2,9.5h0.1h0.3C64.8,14.6,50.2,0,32.3,0z"/> 
    </g>
    </g>
    </svg>



    
    <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 65.01 65.01">
      <defs>
      <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <rect class="cls-1" x=".26" y=".25" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <path id="Path_1028" data-name="Path 1028" d="m18.5,32.5c0-7.73,6.27-14,14-14s14,6.27,14,14-6.27,14-14,14h0c-7.73,0-14-6.27-14-14"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" data-name="Path 1029" class="cls-2" d="m24.03,31.66c5.8-1.48,7-2.68,8.48-8.48,1.48,5.8,2.68,7,8.48,8.48-5.8,1.48-7,2.68-8.48,8.48-1.48-5.8-2.68-7-8.48-8.48"/>
    <g>
    <path d="m65.01,32.5C65.01,14.55,50.46,0,32.51,0S0,14.55,0,32.5"/>
    <path d="m0,32.5c0,17.95,14.55,32.5,32.5,32.5s32.5-14.55,32.5-32.5m-.25,0c-6.44,5.71-18.47,9.55-32.25,9.55S6.7,38.21.25,32.5"/>
    </g>
    </svg>


    <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64.75 64.75">
      <circle cx="32.38" cy="32.38" r="32.38"/>
    </svg>
```

So far I was tryging to animate paths, but I don't think it is good idea of doing that:

```
#Path_1026 {
  animation: path 0.8s infinite linear;
}
#Path_1027 {
  animation: path2 0.8s infinite linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
 @keyframes path {
  0% { d:path('m32.25,14.36c13.2-.06,25.45,6.83,32.25,18.15C64.64,14.69,50.32.14,32.5,0,14.69-.14.14,14.19,0,32c0,.17,0,.34,0,.51C6.8,21.19,19.05,14.29,32.25,14.36');
  }
   25% {
  d: path('M32.3,0C14.3,00.3,14.60.3,32.5H0C6.4,26.8,18.5,23,32.2,23s25.8,3.8,32.2,9.5h0.1h0.3C64.8,14.6,50.2,0,32.3,0z');
   }
 ....
 }
```

itp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an attempt to animate your SVG with D3's transition:

```js
const changeState = (state) => {
   let upper, lower;
   if (state) {
     upper = "M 0,100 A 100,100 1 1 1 200,100 Q 100,100 0,100 Z";
     lower = "M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0 0 200,100 Q 100,100 0,100 Z";
   }
   else {
     upper = "M 0,100 A 100,100 1 1 1 200,100 Q 100,0 0,100 Z";
     lower = "M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0 0 200,100 Q 100,200 0,100 Z";
   }
   
   d3.select('#upper')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('d', upper)
   d3.select('#lower')
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr('d', lower)
    
  setTimeout(() => changeState(!state), 1000);  
}

changeState(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path id="upper" d="M 0,100 A 100,100 1 1 1 200,100 Q 100,0 0,100 Z"/>
  <path id="lower" d="M 0,100 A 100,100 0 0 0 200,100 Q 100,200 0,100 Z"/>
  <circle r="40" cx="100" cy="100" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not animation, but by applying both a fadeIn and fadeOut **opacity**, the 4 **overlapping** SVGs *kinda* look like they are animated.

The only benefit is: **you do not have to change one single byte in your 4 SVGs**

Wrap all 4 SVGs in a native JavaScript Web Component (JSWC) `<svg-rotate>`

The Web Component **moves** all 4 SVGs from *lightDOM* to *shadowDOM*

Now we can apply **"scoped" CSS in *shadowDOM*** without affecting anything else in the page.

The SVGs are `position:absolute` displayed on top of each other

A `setInterval` function then rotates through the SVGs, adding/removing the `fadeIn` class controlling the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations.

With an optional `duration` **attribute**

```js
customElements.define("svg-rotate", class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
      .attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
      .innerHTML = `
        <style>
          svg {max-height: 180px;position:absolute; --s: 0.6s}      
          svg.fadeIn       {animation: fadeIn  var(--s) forwards}
          svg:not(.fadeIn) {animation: fadeOut var(--s) forwards}
          @keyframes fadeIn  { 0% { opacity: 0 } 100% { opacity: 1 } }
          @keyframes fadeOut { 0% { opacity: 1 } 100% { opacity: 0 } }
          #Path_1028 { fill:blue }
        </style>`;
  }
  connectedCallback(){
    setTimeout(()=>{ // wait till all SVGs in lightDOM are parsed
      let duration =  this.getAttribute("duration") || 1000;
      let current = 0;
      let SVGs = this.querySelectorAll("svg"); // get all SVGs in lightDOM
      this.shadowRoot.append(...SVGs); // move ALL SVGs to shadowDOM
      let show = () => {
        SVGs[current].classList.remove('fadeIn');
        current = (current + 1) % SVGs.length;
        SVGs[current].classList.add('fadeIn');
      };
      show();
      this.intervalId = setInterval(show, duration);
      this.onclick = () => animate = !animate; // toggle animation on click
    });
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
});
```

```html
<svg-rotate duration="600">

<!-- I have not changed anything in your original SVGs -->

  <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 
    0 64.5 65.01">
      <defs>
       <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
      }
      .cls-2 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <rect class="cls-1" x="0" y=".25" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <g id="Group_242" data-name="Group 242">
    <path id="Path_1026" data-name="Path 1026" d="m32.25,14.36c13.2-.06,25.45,6.83,32.25,18.15C64.64,14.69,50.32.14,32.5,0,14.69-.14.14,14.19,0,32c0,.17,0,.34,0,.51C6.8,21.19,19.05,14.29,32.25,14.36"/>
    <path id="Path_1027" data-name="Path 1027" d="m32.25,50.65C19.05,50.72,6.8,43.82,0,32.5c-.14,17.81,14.18,32.36,32,32.5,17.81.14,32.36-14.18,32.5-32,0-.17,0-.34,0-.51-6.8,11.31-19.05,18.21-32.25,18.15"/>
    <path id="Path_1028" data-name="Path 1028" d="m18.25,32.5c0-7.73,6.27-14,14-14s14,6.27,14,14-6.27,14-14,14h0c-7.73,0-14-6.27-14-14"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" data-name="Path 1029" class="cls-2" d="m23.77,31.66c5.8-1.48,7-2.68,8.48-8.48,1.48,5.8,2.68,7,8.48,8.48-5.8,1.48-7,2.68-8.48,8.48-1.48-5.8-2.68-7-8.48-8.48"/>
    </g>
    </svg>




  <svg version="1.1" id="Warstwa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 64.5 65" style="enable-background:new 0 0 64.5 65;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    </style>
    <rect y="0.2" class="st0" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <g id="Group_242">
    <path id="Path_1028" d="M18.2,32.5c0-7.7,6.3-14,14-14s14,6.3,14,14s-6.3,14-14,14l0,0C24.5,46.5,18.2,40.2,18.2,32.5"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" class="st1" d="M23.8,31.7c5.8-1.5,7-2.7,8.5-8.5c1.5,5.8,2.7,7,8.5,8.5c-5.8,1.5-7,2.7-8.5,8.5
        C30.8,34.3,29.6,33.1,23.8,31.7"/>
    <g>
    <path d="M32.2,50.7C19,50.7,6.8,43.8,0,32.5C-0.1,50.3,14.2,64.9,32,65s32.4-14.2,32.5-32c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5
            C57.7,43.8,45.5,50.7,32.2,50.7z"/>
    <path d="M32.3,0C14.3,0-0.3,14.6-0.3,32.5H0C6.4,26.8,18.5,23,32.2,23s25.8,3.8,32.2,9.5h0.1h0.3C64.8,14.6,50.2,0,32.3,0z"/> 
    </g>
    </g>
    </svg>




  <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 65.01 65.01">
      <defs>
      <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <rect class="cls-1" x=".26" y=".25" width="64.5" height="64.5"/>
    <path id="Path_1028" data-name="Path 1028" d="m18.5,32.5c0-7.73,6.27-14,14-14s14,6.27,14,14-6.27,14-14,14h0c-7.73,0-14-6.27-14-14"/>
    <path id="Path_1029" data-name="Path 1029" class="cls-2" d="m24.03,31.66c5.8-1.48,7-2.68,8.48-8.48,1.48,5.8,2.68,7,8.48,8.48-5.8,1.48-7,2.68-8.48,8.48-1.48-5.8-2.68-7-8.48-8.48"/>
    <g>
    <path d="m65.01,32.5C65.01,14.55,50.46,0,32.51,0S0,14.55,0,32.5"/>
    <path d="m0,32.5c0,17.95,14.55,32.5,32.5,32.5s32.5-14.55,32.5-32.5m-.25,0c-6.44,5.71-18.47,9.55-32.25,9.55S6.7,38.21.25,32.5"/>
    </g>
    </svg>


  <svg id="Warstwa_1" data-name="Warstwa 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64.75 64.75">
      <circle cx="32.38" cy="32.38" r="32.38"/>
    </svg>
</svg-rotate>
```